# Selection of second columns data based on match of first column with another text file in python

Tags: numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I have little knowledge of numpy arrays and iterations. I have two input
   files. First columns of both files represents time in milliseconds. 
   Input file 1 is reference or simulated value. Input file 2 is obtained from  test value. I want to compare(plot second vs first ) second column of input-2 
file with second column of first file if and only if when there is match of time in first column in corresponding files.
 I am trying it through iterations but could not find proper results yet.How 
 to find index when there is a match?

```
import numpy as np
my_file=np.genfromtxt('path/input1.txt')
Sim_val=np.genfromtxt('path/input2.txt')
inp1=my_file[:,0]
inp12=my_file[:,1]
inpt2=Sim_val[:,0]
inpt21=Sim_val[:,1]
xarray=np.array(inp1)
yarray=np.array(inp12)
data=np.array([xarray,yarray])
ldata=data.T

zarray=np.array(inpt2)
tarray=np.array(inpt21)
mdata=np.array([zarray,tarray])
kdata=mdata.T

i=np.searchsorted(kdata[:,0],ldata[:,0])
print i
```

My inputfile-2  &              Inputfile-1 is

```
   0        5               0        5
  100       6               50       6
  200      10               200      15
  300      12               350      12
  400      15 # Obtained    400      15    #Simulated Value
  500      20   #Value      500      25
  600      0                650      0
  700      11               700      11
  800      12               850      8
  900      19               900      19
 1000     10                1000     3
```

Having really a hard time with numpy arrays and iterations. 
  Please anybody suggest how can I solve above problem. In-fact I 
  have other columns too but  all manipulation is depend  on match of first column(Time match).

Once again very much thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like

```
import numpy as np

simulated = np.array([
    (0, 5),
    (100, 6),
    (200, 10),
    (300, 12),
    (400, 15),
    (500, 20),
    (600, 0),
    (700, 11),
    (800, 12),
    (900, 19),
    (1000, 10)
])

actual = np.array([
    (0, 5),
    (50, 6),
    (200, 15),
    (350, 12),
    (400, 15),
    (500, 25),
    (650, 0),
    (700, 11),
    (850, 8),
    (900, 19),
    (1000, 3)
])


def indexes_where_match(A, B):
    """ an iterator that goes over the indexes of wherever the entries in A's first-col and B's first-col match """
    return (i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)) if a[0] == b[0])


def main():
    for i in indexes_where_match(simulated, actual):
        print(simulated[i][1], 'should be compared to', actual[i][1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You could also use column-slicing, like this:

```
simulated_time, simulated_values = simulated[..., 0], simulated[..., 1:]
actual_time, actual_values = actual[..., 0], actual[..., 1:]

indexes_where_match = (i for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(simulated_time, actual_time)) if a == b)

for i in indexes_where_match:
    print(simulated_values[i], 'should be compared to', actual_values[i])


# outputs:
# [5] should be compared to [5]
# [10] should be compared to [15]
# [15] should be compared to [15]
# [20] should be compared to [25]
# [11] should be compared to [11]
# [19] should be compared to [19]
# [10] should be compared to [3]
```

Comment: yes I want exactly this one. Whenever time will match I will compare the second column of both the files. I will check your one .

Comment: Just modification  of same question . If simulating values are lets say 100 and actual values are 70. And out of them 50 are matching . Means both are generating data at different rates. So now how can I subtract matched actual values from simulating values.   In short if 5000 msec of simulated values is at 20th index and 5000 msec of actual values is at occurring at 15th index. Now how I can compare other two columns for this two indexes.

Comment: @ Nitsan BenHanoch in my first case both are of same length. Hence at the same place for same index data is matching for both columns. Now being different length index i is not same for both columns of data.

Comment: @ Nitsan BenHanoch  . My first case data was of same length and occurring at  same place. So index was matching. But in this case both are at different rates. So how index is not common for both . In this case how to solve for two indices